# Can we provide a raw stream of microphone data Unit8List as a Input to ffmpeg and save the output file as .wav or .mp3

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, stream, pipe, audio-streaming

The goal is to listen to a live microphone stream (**don't want to store it locally**)and try to pass it to the RTSP server or to a .mp3 or .wav file locally.

FFmpeg lib :[ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter)

Mic Stream lib : https://pub.dev/packages/mic_stream

```
 stream = await MicStream.microphone(
        audioSource: AudioSource.DEFAULT,
        sampleRate: 44100,
        channelConfig: ChannelConfig.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
        audioFormat: AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

listener = stream!.listen((recordedData) async {
  await processData(recordedData);
});
```

And in Process data, I want to convert this raw Unit8List data to .mp3 or transmit it to rtsp server live.

**any of the commands i want to execute**

```
Future<void> processData(Uint8List data) async {
//var command = '-i "$data" -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp -y "$RtspUrl"';


//var command = '-i "$data" "/storage/emulated/0/Download/androidvideo.mp3"';

FFmpegKit.execute(command).then((session) async {
  final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
  final logs = await session.getLogs();
  for (var element in logs) {
    print('logs:${element.getMessage()}');
  }
  if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
    print('Command execution completed successfully.');
  } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
    print('Command execution completed CANCEL.');
    listener.cancel();
  } else {
    print('Command execution completed ERROR.');
    listener.cancel();
  }
});
}
```